# How to make god rays with png transparent image

Tags: light

Working with cycles. Can we create god rays with the png transparent image. I have setup all the scene. With sun lamp and a transparent png image. But the light is not going through the image and making the rays. Any suggestion how it works. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Rays are there because of some atmospheric dust or fog. Dont know if the PNG let the light comes through as glass material (I would expect it does), but if there arent any particles, you wont see any light beams.

Answer (score 1):

Decrease the *Density* of your *Volume Scatter* down to 0.007, switch from *Sun* to *Spot*, increase its *Power* up to  20,000, and Alleluia!!

[image]

Comment: @ Great result. Suggestion. Can i use a plane instead of spot, Reason i want to cover all the image. With the spot light its covering center part rest of the image its black. Thanks

Comment: sure, a plane seems to work, you need to test

Comment: i tested all the light is spreading. The god rays effect not be achieved.https://imgur.com/a/febcOF5

Comment: what do you mean? if you want a god ray effect, try to close your space like a real church, so that it doesn't affect everywhere, and use a strong light, otherwise you won't have a god ray effect. I didn't have to use a closed space because I've used a Spot